# Powershell Export-CSV

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I'm just having problems trying to export the following to a CSV, I've tried putting the `Export-CSV` within the `Foreach-Object` loop to no avail.

I want to put the server name `$server` in the first column and the description `$description` in the second.

In an earlier version, I was able to make a text file using `Out-File -append .\outa.txt -InputObject $_.Name,$description` but the formatting did not work well.

```
$server = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "*Server*" -and Name -Notlike "*DOM*"} 
$server | ForEach-Object {
    $Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$_.Name) 
    $RegKey = $Reg.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters")
    $description = $RegKey.GetValue("srvcomment") 
} | Export-Csv .\out1.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ForEach` as oppose to `ForEach-Object`:

```
$server = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "*Server*" -and Name -Notlike "*DOM*"} 

foreach($s in  $server){

    # replaced $_ with $s
    $Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$s.Name) 
    $RegKey= $Reg.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters")
    $description = $RegKey.GetValue("srvcomment") 

   # casting as array is required to use +=
   # disclaimer: the array is destroyed and rebuilt on each run.
   [array]$myData += New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Server      = $s.Name
        Description = $description
   }
}

# If you want a CSV without the top info line, use the notypeinfo switch
# Select-Object gives you the column order you want.
$myData | Select-Object Server,Description | Export-Csv .\out1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Edit - comment answer**
It is possible to do it without creating an array and from inside the loop, but an object is required by `Export-Csv` AFAIK.

`ForEach-Object`:

```
$server = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "*Server*" -and Name -Notlike "*DOM*"} 
$server | ForEach-Object {
    $Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$_.Name) 
    $RegKey = $Reg.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters")
    New-object psobject -Property @{Server=$_.Name;Description=$RegKey.GetValue("srvcomment")} | Export-Csv .\out1.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

`ForEach`:

```
$server = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "*Server*" -and Name -Notlike "*DOM*"} 
foreach($s in  $server){
    $Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$s.Name) 
    $RegKey= $Reg.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters")
    New-object psobject -Property @{Server=$s.Name;Description=$RegKey.GetValue("srvcomment")} | Export-Csv .\out1.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

If you have problems with the values, brackets/subexpressions can help:

```
New-object psobject -Property @{Server=($_.Name);Description=($RegKey.GetValue("srvcomment"))} | Export-Csv .\out1.csv -NoTypeInformation
New-object psobject -Property @{Server=$($_.Name);Description=$($RegKey.GetValue("srvcomment"))} | Export-Csv .\out1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: That works for me thanks. Is it possible to do it without creating an array?  Seems like an extra step - there must be a way to put the output while in the loop.

Comment: @yoscar See edit. Finally messed around with `ForEach-Object` as well

Answer (score 0):

Your ForEach-Object only contains statements (variable assignments). It's not returning anything. You need to return something, otherwise you're passing an empty pipeline to `Export-CSV`.

I'm guessing that, instead of setting variables called `$Reg`, `$RegKey`, and `$description` (and then never using their values), what you actually want to do is create columns in the CSV called `Reg`, `RegKey`, and `description`. In that case, you want to yield a `[PSCustomObject]` (with those properties added to it) each time through the loop.

```
$server = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "*Server*" -and Name -Notlike "*DOM*"} 
$server | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject] @{
        Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$_.Name) 
        RegKey = $Reg.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters")
        description = $RegKey.GetValue("srvcomment") 
    }
} | Export-Csv .\out1.csv
```